# VHDL report statement ignored

Tags: vhdl, quartus

To learn VHDL, I'm implementing my own custom CPU with VHDL.

Tired of writing opcode bit pattern manually, I want to create very simple "assembler" to create bit pattern.

Here is current implemenation of such assembler:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.utility.all;

package assembler is
    function encode_opcode(cmd: string; re: integer; rd: integer; ra: integer; rb: integer; imm: integer) return std_logic_vector;
end;

package body assembler is
    function to_lower(x: character) return character is
        constant posA: integer := character'pos('A');
        constant posZ: integer := character'pos('Z');
        constant posLowerA: integer := character'pos('a');
        constant posX: integer := character'pos(x);
    begin
        if posA <= posX and posX <= posZ then
            return character'val(posX - posA + posLowerA);
        else
            return x;
        end if;
    end;

    function to_lower(x: string) return string is
        variable r: string(x'range);
    begin
        for i in x'range loop
            r(i) := to_lower(x(i));
        end loop;
        return r;
    end;

    function encode_cmd(cmd: string) return std_logic_vector is
        constant cmd2: string(1 to cmd'length) := cmd;
        variable cmd3: string(1 to 5) := "-----";
    begin
        if cmd'length > 5 then
            report "Illegal command: " & cmd severity error;
            return "";
        end if;
        for i in cmd2'range loop
            cmd3(i) := cmd2(i);
        end loop;
        case to_lower(cmd3) is
            -- Group 1: Memory access (omitted)
            -- Group 2: Addition
            when "addu-" => return "00100000";
            when "subu-" => return "00100001";
            when "add--" => return "00100010";
            when "sub--" => return "00100011";
            -- Group 3: Multiplication
            when "multu" => return "00110000";
            when "divu-" => return "00110001";
            when "mult-" => return "00110010";
            when "div--" => return "00110011";
            -- Group 4: Bitwise (omitted)
            -- Group 5: Shift
            when "shf--" => return "01010000";
            when "shfu-" => return "01010001";
            when "rot--" => return "01010010";
            -- Group 6: Branch absolute (omitted)
            -- Group 7: Branch relative (omitted)
            when others =>
                report "Illegal command: " & cmd severity error;
                return "";
        end case;
    end;

    function encode_opcode(cmd: string; re: integer; rd: integer; ra: integer; rb: integer; imm: integer) return std_logic_vector is
    begin
        return encode_cmd(cmd) & encode_unsigned(re, 5) & encode_unsigned(rd, 5) & encode_unsigned(ra, 5) & encode_unsigned(rb, 5) & encode_signed(imm, 4);
    end;
end;
```

Here is definition of encode_unsigned and encode_signed function:

```
function encode_unsigned(x: integer; n: integer) return std_logic_vector is
begin
    return std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(x, n));
end;

function encode_signed(x: integer; n: integer) return std_logic_vector is
begin
    return std_logic_vector(to_signed(x, n));
end;
```

Here is usage of encode_opcode function:

```
function rom_contents(addr: std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
begin
    case decode_unsigned(addr) is
        when 0 => return encode_opcode("ADDu", 0, 1, 0, 0, 2);
        when 1 => return encode_opcode("ADD", 0, 2, 0, 0, -8);
        when 2 => return encode_signed(11, 32);
        when 3 => return encode_opcode("MULT", 0, 3, 1, 2, 0);
        when 6 => return encode_opcode("ADD", 0, 4, 3, 0, 0);
        when 8 => return encode_opcode("ADD", 0, 16, 0, 0, -8);
        when 9 => return encode_signed(16#12345678#, 32);
        when 11 => return encode_opcode("ROT", 31, 30, 16, 0, 4);
        when 12 => return encode_opcode("ROT", 29, 28, 30, 0, 4);
        when others => return (31 downto 0 => '0');
    end case;
end;
```

Whenever I make mistake and wrote something like `encode_opcode("ROTE", 31, 30, 16, 0, 4);`, I want to get error message like `Illegal command: ROTE`. However, it doesn't create any error message, and the length of return value of encode_opcode becomes 24 silently. (if there were no mistakes, lenght should be 32.)

Using enum for command would be too hard, as some of command looks like `AND`, `XOR`, `GFu>`, `GT<=`.

I'm using Quartus Prime Lite Edition version 18.0

UPDATE: usage of rom_contents:

```
entity instruction_memory_controller is
    port (
        clock: in std_logic;
        addr: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        q: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
    );
end;

architecture RTL of instruction_memory_controller is
begin
    process(clock)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clock) then
            q <= rom_contents(addr);
        end if;
    end process;
end;
```

When I entered wrong command, `q <= rom_contnts(addr)` marked error due to mismatch size (24 vs 32).

When I changed return value of illegal command from `""` to `"XXXXXXXX"`, it compiles without any error/warning. (My expection is that it triggers `Illegal command` error by report statement.)

Comment: The normal case statement doesn't support don't-care s. You need to use the VHDL-2008 case? statement. [More info here](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/vhdl_200x_small/). However "rote" is four chars long, while you are checking for five chars. That will not work. You should switch to if-elsif statements (and use the matching equality operator ?= for the don't care s).

Comment: @JHBonarius :: The first few lines of encode_cmd makes "normalize" command string to 5-length lower-case string padded with '-' character. Here, '-' is not "don't care" std_logic_vector signal; it is character whicn consists string.

Comment: @Venusaur: congratulations for you first steps in VHDL! I wish all VHDL beginners had such a good understanding and advanced use of the language.

Comment: @Venusaur: compilation is not simulation. The error should be raised at simulation, not compilation.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet 1) When I put report statement inside encode_unsigned and encode_signed function, (almost) all of my entities reports that message during Analysis & Synthesis stage, except this instruction_memory_controller entity. 2) It seems that Quartus runs simulation with [logic-cell-level implementation](https://gist.github.com/BupjaeLee/e1e7afd17fe3cc1ca830602df0c2b99d); In this case, I can't expect my error message in simulation stage.

Comment: Ok, maybe you should add a [mcve], so we can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On the length of the returned vectors: your `encode_cmd` function returns an empty vector when an illegal opcode is encountered. So, the total length of the vector returned by `encode_opcode` is not 32 but 24... Return `"00000000"` or any other 8-bits long vector if you want 32 bits results in all cases.
2. About the missing error message: It shows up with Modelsim. As you do not show what you do with `rom_contents` we cannot guess whether the vector length mismatch will raise a simulation error or not. If it does, could it be that with Quartus it takes precedence over the `report "Illegal command...` and that the latter is never fired? Or could it be that you missed the error message because it was not the last printed one?

Notes:

- If you want the simulation to really stop when an illegal opcode is encountered try maybe `severity failure` instead of `severity error`, or find the option of your simulator that selects the severity level above which the simulation stops.
- You use `std_logic` and `std_logic_vector` which are resolved types. Considering your design I doubt that you really have multiple drive situations. You should, maybe consider `std_ulogic` and `std_ulogic_vector`, instead, as it would be safer. And as you apparently use the VHDL 2008 flavor, it is the same with `signed` and `unsigned` that you could substitute by `u_signed` and `u_unsigned`. All in all it would bring the benefit that unwanted multiple drive situations would raise errors.

**EDITS** after comments have been exchanged:

Quartus is a synthesizer. So, there is a chance that it synthesizes your design before simulating it at gate level. If this is true then you must realize something important: `report` statements are ignored by the synthesis process because they have no hardware equivalent. So, the best you can expect with Quartus is that it detects that a `report` statement is always reached and decides to show it during the synthesis process. This is possible in some cases because a synthesizer tries to simplify the design by propagating constants:

```
constant condition: boolean := true;
...
if condition then
    report 'Foo bar';
end if;
```

becomes:

```
report 'Foo bar';
```

Unfortunately, in more complex examples, like yours for instance, it is far more difficult to detect that a `report` statement is always reached. This is because it is reached only after a given number of clock cycles, when your address reaches the faulty ROM entry. Don't expect a logic synthesizer to detect this.

Solutions:

1. Use a real simulator, like GHDL or Modelsim, for instance, to validate your design.
2. Implement a real error signal, instead of an abstract, simulation-oriented, `report` statement. And monitor this signal during post-synthesis simulation (and during execution on your hardware target). This will be the first step toward a real *invalid instruction* exception of your processor.

Note about VHDL 2008: if you use the  `'-'` (don't care) value in case statements as a way to match any value, then you are using VHDL 2008, I think. It has been introduced in 2008, if I remember well. Before that it was a value like any other value (except in the `ieee.numeric_std.std_match` function).

Comment: And it shows that a vector length mismatch error is indeed raised.

Comment: `severity failure` instead `severity error` doesn't help; I still get no error/warning. Also, AFAIK, VHDL-2008 is not supported widely, so I want to avoid using VHDL-2008 if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and answer. Now it is crystal clear what happened. 


For the '-' character used in encode_cmd, what I'm trying to do is normalize command from "ADDu" to "addu-" and then perform exact string match; I'll always use std_match whenever I need to match std_logic_vector type.